# Conditional Formatting from another sheet with checkbox

Tags: google-sheets

I know this has been asked already but I can't get it to work in my formula. I currently have two sheets, the first being `Sheet1` and the second being `Sheet2`. In `Sheet1!B1` I have a checkbox, and `Sheet2!A1` I would like to be filled in green if the box is checked.

The custom formula I tried in the conditional formatting input for `Sheet2!A1` is `=INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!B1")="TRUE"` but it doesn't seem to do anything.

This is part of a more complicated sheet but this is the smallest replicable version of the issue. Here is the sheet if you want to look: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lYUbHTpSDl8vVRltsC02n07vA0cwRhhQVGJMqzBrpxE/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the checkbox is a boolean value that is standalone. by wrapping them to double quotes you turn boolean into plain text strings. use:

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!B1")=TRUE
```